# Beginner Java: Simple grade average code

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the different parts of the code but I need to ask for individual help at this point. So here's my issue: I'm building a simple grade average program for my first java programming class. I want to save 4 grade inputs, then display an average. Eventually I am going to display letter grades based on that average. I think this error is saying I am not initializing **finalGrade**.

But I'm lost. An explanation of what is happening would be great so I can actually learn this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GradeAverage{

   public static  Double gradeQ1; //gradeQ are grades for the respective quarters
   public static  Double gradeQ2;
   public static  Double gradeQ3;
   public static  Double gradeQ4;
   public static  String studentName;
   public static  Double finalGrade = ((gradeQ1 + gradeQ2 + gradeQ3 + gradeQ4) / 4);

   public static void main(String args[]) {


   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


   studentName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your first and last name.");
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks " + studentName + ", let's get started!");

   gradeQ1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What was your grade in the first quarter?")); // gets grade and saves it as a double gradeQ1
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered " + gradeQ1);
   //double gradeQ1 = input.nextDouble();

   gradeQ2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What was your grade in the second quarter?")); 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered " + gradeQ2);

   gradeQ3 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What was your grade in the third quarter?")); 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered " + gradeQ3);

   gradeQ4 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What was your grade in the fourth quarter?")); 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered " + gradeQ4);

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks " + studentName + ", Your average was " + finalGrade);

   }
}



JGRASP error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GradeAverage.<clinit>(GradeAverage.java:15)
```

Comment: Right - you need to understand the difference between Double the object and double the primitive.  As a beginner, you're making the classic mistake of worrying too much about the user interface.  I'd get the grade calculations working first with a text interface.

Comment: Wouldn't I have the same issue?  I just thought it was easier to use a dialog box as opposed to command line.  Calculations are simple: sum/count. The execution is what's killing me

Comment: here is your error  public static  Double finalGrade = ((gradeQ1 + gradeQ2 + gradeQ3 + gradeQ4) / 4);. At this stage, gradeQi are not yet initialized. Their all equal to null...

Comment: But then again it is not your only error.

Comment: Haha! Ok well thanks. I got it to work with your initial correction, and adding this to end of the code:
 double finalGrade = (gradeQ1 + gradeQ2 + gradeQ3 + gradeQ4)/ 4;
   
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks " + studentName + ", Your average was " + finalGrade);

Comment: "The execution is killing me" - yes, that's correct.  You would still have the same issue.  My advice is for the future if you continue to program.  Decomposing problems well is an essential skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program fail on:

```
public static  Double finalGrade = ((gradeQ1 + gradeQ2 + gradeQ3 + gradeQ4) / 4);
```

because grade* are object and they haven't got initialization. The program could work only in case you use double instead Double. The different is that the first isn't an object and its default value is 0.0 , while Double is an object with default value null. This create the nullPointerException.

Second your finalGrade will be 0, you must before read the value and then set the finalGrade's value.

```
...
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You entered " + gradeQ4);

finalGrade = ((gradeQ1 + gradeQ2 + gradeQ3 + gradeQ4) / 4);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks " + studentName + ", Your average was " + finalGrade);
```